# shell_exec not working with ssh command in virtual machine

Tags: php, shell, ssh, terminal, shell-exec

I have a script `PHP` that this has a command `ssh` with `ls -la` to list the files and directories. But when I run the script, it returns me error code 255 in addition to the following error message:

```
Could not create directory '/usr/sbin/.ssh'. ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-`askpass): No such file or directory Host key verification failed.`
```

When I use sudo on the ssh command, it returns me another error, being the following:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

The authentication key is already inside the `know_hosts` file and when I run the same command inside the `terminal`, connecting via `ssh`, everything works perfectly. The key is inside the `Downloads` folder and her permission is `0644`. I've tried several possible solutions, but none have been able to help me solve the problem.

Here is the code used:

```
$oldldpath = getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH');
putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=");
var_dump(shell_exec("ssh -i $key_file user@ip \"ls -la ~\" 2>&1"));
putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$oldldpath");
```

**Editing - Correcting a part of the problem**

The problem `Could not create directory '/usr/sbin/.ssh'` has been fixed from the creation of the `.ssh` folder inside `/usr/sbin`. Now, when the script runs again, it returns the rest of the problem, which is as follows:

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory Host key verification failed.
```

**Edit 2:**

The above error was corrected with the installation of `ssh_askpass`, from the following code below:

```
sudo apt-get install ssh-askpass
```

However, after the corrections on the described errors, another error was generated, being the following:

```
No protocol specified Error: Can't open display: :0.0 Host key verification failed.
```

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo`? The apache user might not have rights

Comment: Unless you have the keyfile in a directory that apache can read, and apache has permissions to read the keyfile, it won't work. By default, ssh requires the keyfile to only be readable/writeable by the owner, no other user can access it.

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa Yes and this information I supplemented in the question.

Comment: @aynber I updated the question with the information you requested.

Comment: It sounds like SSH is configured to use an askpass program, but either one isn't install or it's not configured for that user. Also make sure that `$key_file` has the full path and not a relative one. Echo your shell_exec command and try running it directly, preferably as another user (the web user if you can gain shell access to it)

Comment: I'm going to say you might need to check over at https://superuser.com, since this seems to do more with permissions and ssh setup than php code.

Comment: @aynber I'll check that out. If anything, I will update the issue again.